# Getter/setter but for nested attributes?

Tags: python, properties

Suppose I have two classes. The simple `Square` class:

```py
class Square:
    def __init__(self, side):
        self.side = side
```

And the slightly more complex `MyClass` class:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, square=None):
        if square is None:
            self.square = Square()
        else:
            self.square = square

        self.rounded_side = round(self.square.side)
```

I instantiate a `MyClass` object like so:

```py
myObj = MyClass()
```

In this situation, how can one achieve the following behavior?

1. Changing `myObj.rounded_side` to `X`, automatically changes `myObj.square.side` also to `X`.
2. Changing `myObj.square.side` to `X`, automatically changes `myObj.rounded_side` to `round(X)`.

If possible, in a way that doesn't require any modifications to the `Square` class (this is a simplified version of the problem I'm currently facing; in the original version, I don't have access to the code for `Square`).

---

What I tried so far:

- My first attempt was to transform `rounded_side` into a property. That makes it possible to obtain behavior 1. However, I fail to see how I can transform `square` also into a property, in a way that makes it possible to obtain behavior 2.
- I also thought about making `MyClass` inherit from `Square`, so that both attributes are in the same depth, but then I'd lose some the desired structure of my class (I rather have the user access `myObj.square.side`, than `myObj.side`)

---

If someone is interested, the actual problem I'm facing:

I'm writing a game in pygame, and my `Player` class has an attribute for its position, which is an array with two floats (2D position). This is used for determining where the player is, and for deciding how to update it's position in the next update step of the game's physics.

However, I also want to have a [`Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) attribute in the `Player` class (which holds the information about a rectangle around the player's image), to be used when displaying the player in the screen, and when inferring collisions. The `Rect` class uses integers to store the position of the rectangle (pixel coordinates).

So as to be able to store the position information of the player in a float, but also use the `Rect` class for convenience, I thought about having this dependency between them, where changing one alters also the other accordingly.

Comment: Why didn't you succeed in making `rounded_side` a property? The setter can set `self.square.side` directly. But does it make sense for that to be settable; how would you "unround" to find the true value?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think he means adding decorator `@property` and adding that behaviour to the setter

Comment: Should the rounded version actually be settable? A situation where you do `thing.rounded_side = 4.2; assert thing.rounded_side == 4.2` and get an assertion error seems somewhat counter-intuitive. The rounded position should always be derived from the actual position, which is what should get updated; make it read-only.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: There are some assignments that make sense for the rounded version. For instance, I use it for collision detection: when two objects collide (which is checked using the rounded version, since I want to check whether they collide in pixel coordinates), I set their rounded down positions to the ones just before collision, in pixel coordinates (i.e. they end up touching pixels, but with no intersection).

Comment: @jonrsharpe: And after a collision, I set their rounded down positions, instead of their actual positions, because it's more convenient to use the `Rect` attributes to set the borders of the Player's rectangle to a given coordinate, instead of the center position of it. (I'm now referring to the actual problem I'm facing, now added to the end of my question).

Answer (score 0):

As you've said, make `rounded_side` a property, but have it access the value in `self.square` for both getting and setting.

```
@property
def rounded_side(self):
    return self.square.side

@rounded_side.setter
def rounded_side(self, side):
    self.square.side = side
```

Now, setting `rounded_side` will use the setter which sets the value in square; setting the value on square directly will mean that it would be looked up from there by the property getter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I understood you correctly, then I wouldn't actually store the `rounded_side` value, it would be inferred when needed, directly from the `square.side` value. Unfortunately, this wouldn't be possible if `square.side` was the rounded down value, and `rounded_side` the one before rounding, correct? Since you wouldn't be able to infer `rounded_side` from `square.side`.

Comment: Also, I guess you meant `return round(self.square.side)` for the first function, no?

Comment: I now feel like you answered exactly what I asked, but this unfortunately doesn't solve the current problem I'm facing (because the simplified version that I posted as a question has a particularity that I didn't think was relevant, i.e. the rounded value is the nested one, not the other way around). In this case, should I accept your answer and ask again, or edit my question?